# What you said is/are both true and false?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

**What he said is both true and false.**

**What he said are both true and false.**

Which one of these sentence is correct?

Which word can be considered as a subject in these sentences?

Answer (score 3):

The first one is correct. What he said is the subject, and since what he said is *a* statement, it is a singular object, and thus, the verb must be conjugated accordingly.